# htaccess invisibly rewrite folder

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple-domains with different content on one server in the directory /html/, which serves all domains, like example1.com, example2.com, example3.com, example4.com.

This works fine.

I now need to have 2 different(!) wordpress-installations. From the outside I would like to have:

```
example1.com -> No Blog
example2.com/blog/
example3.com -> No Blog
example4.com/blog/
```

The internal path-structure on the server should look like:

```
/html/
/blog-for-server2/
/blog-for-server4/
```

Because otherwise the content-management-system in /html/ gets messed up. In fact this is almost like having independent subdomains for the blogs and pointing them to different pathes on the server (but I don't want to use subdomains).

Any ideas?

Comment: Either set-up the `RewriteRule`s in your VirtualHost directives in Apache's httpd-vhosts.conf file or do a messy load of redirects in a root .htaccess file with a `RewriteCond` like `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example1.com`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already created the domains in Apache's *httpd-vhosts.conf* file you can create the redirects inside that, something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/servers/common_root/html

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/blog/? /blog-for-server-1
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    DocumentRoot /home/servers/common_root/html

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/blog/? /blog-for-server-2
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise you can do it in a root *.htaccess* but it's messy:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example1.com
RewriteRule ^blog /blog-for-server-1

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example2.com
RewriteRule ^blog /blog-for-server-2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have no access to the httpd-vhosts.conf file, so I tried to add it in the htaccess. The problem seems to be that /blog-for-server-2 is always relative to the Doc-Root /html/, so it doesn't work if this path is on the same level as the Doc-Root.

Comment: If it's the same level (or above) the docroot, you can't do it through .htaccess (as you can't access the filesystem) ... and as you've not got access to httpd-vhosts.conf I'm pretty sure the only option is to move the `/blog-for-server...` directories under the docroot and deal with redirects using .htaccess.